# How to extend Shake with additional command-line arguments?

Tags: shake-build-system

I'm trying to extend the Shake command line argument, with two goals in mind:

- To take extra flags, e.g. `--foo`.
- To treat non-flag arguments specially depending on the current working directory, so `go` does one thing in the root, and another in the `foobar` directory.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four relevant functions to extend the Shake command line:

- [`shake`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake/docs/Development-Shake.html#v:shake) is the main entry point to Shake, which takes a [`ShakeOptions`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake/docs/Development-Shake.html#t:ShakeOptions) structure describing all the options. If you want an entirely custom command line interface, use any command-line parser to populate these fields.
- [`shakeArgs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake/docs/Development-Shake.html#v:shakeArgs) runs Shake filling in the `ShakeOptions` using the command line arguments, so is useful to get a standard command line with Shake.
- [`shakeArgsWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake/docs/Development-Shake.html#v:shakeArgsWith) takes a list of extra options as its second argument, and logic for how to deal with any non-flag arguments as its third. You can inject new flags, and modify how a non-flag like `go` gets resolved based on any other information you have to hand, including current directory.
- [`shakeOptDescrs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake/docs/Development-Shake.html#v:shakeOptDescrs) gives data types describing flags corresponding to fields in `ShakeOptions`.

As to their relationship, `shake` is the actual build system. `shakeArgsWith` uses the information from `shakeOptDescrs` and any custom flags to build and run a command line parser. `shakeArgs` calls `shakeArgsWith` using no additional flags.

In the specific case of adding a flag or customising the behaviour of a non-flag, `shakeArgsWith` is sufficient. If you need more control, you can build your own parser, perhaps incorporating the existing flags found in `shakeOptDescrs` or not.